# Is it possible to prefix log messages with ServiceStack Logging

Tags: servicestack, nlog

I'm wondering if Service Stack Logging can configured to support this type of context logging?

[Prefix NLog messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572462/how-do-i-add-variables-as-prefix-to-all-my-nlog-messages)

basically I'd like a correlation token to be in very log statement.

Thank you,
Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's currently not in the [ServiceStack.Logging NLog Adapter](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Logging/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Logging.NLog/NLogLogger.cs), so you would need to take a copy of it and customize your local copy of it. A better option would be to send a pull-request and add configurable support for it, so it will end up in the next release of the ServiceStack.Logging NLog Adapter.